# Кто славился своей серьезностью?

Tags: тропы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким сравнением выразить крайнюю степень серьезности? Говорят "смотрит, как Ленин на буржуазию", но "серьезный [о выражении лица в определенный момент], как... буржуазия при виде Ленина"? Нерон при виде горящего Рима? Так притчей во языцех стала легенда о том, что император, наблюдая за полыхающей столицы, пребывал в самом добром расположении духа. Ну подкиньте какую-нибудь идею, мое знание истории дает серьезную течь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут 
зависит еще и от исторических познаний слушателей или читателей. Можно 
вспомнить, что Клеопатра, соблазнив Цезаря и Марка Антония не смогла 
проделать тоже самое с Августом и сказать, - "*Как Октавиан Август на 
Клеопатру*".  Если знания античной истории оставляют желать лучшего 
могут подойти и другие примеры:

- Как Петр Первый на стрельцов (бороду, кафтаны).
- Как народовольцы на царя.
- Как Пиночет на коммунистов.
- Как Саладин на крестоносцев.
- Как Иван Грозный на бояр.
- Как Гитлер на евреев.

Можно вспомнить и современные реалии:

- Как Путин на Ходорковского (Навального).
- Как РПЦ на Пусси Райт.
- Как Новодворская на коммунистов.

Вариантов много, выбор за вами.

---

Теперь понял, что вы имели в виду. Могу предложить следущие варианты:

- Как Цезарь, переходящий Рубикон.
- Как Леонид при Фермопилах
- Как Свобода на барикадах.
- Как Афина Паллада.
- Как Раскольников у старухи-процентщицы.
- Как офицер на присяге.
- Как Жанна д'Арк на костре.

Comment: Мда, вариантов много, спасибо, но меня вполне устраивает и Ленин, взирающий на буржуазию. А вот варианты сравнения серьезного лика, которые я сама себе смогла предложить ("серьезный, как буржуа при виде Ленина", "серьезный, как Нерон при виде пылающего Рима"), меня устраивают не вполне.

Comment: Я имею в виду не серьезный взгляд, которым Иван Грозный взирает на бояр, а серьезный вид, принятый в силу каких угодно причин.
Ну например, так: "Все засмеялись, но Иван Грозный был серьезен, как Нерон при виде пылающего Рима".

Comment: О, спасибо! Как же это я про Леню забыла? Вот уж кому точно было не до смеха. Может быть, кто-нибудь еще захочет высказаться, хотя я знаю, что таким знанием истории здесь отличаетесь только Вы.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы я была в  роли читателя вашего текста, то меня бы порадовало такое сравнение, которое несло бы в себе явно узнаваемый и понятный  комический элемент.

Комическое определяется как несоответствие между содержанием и формой явления, поэтому внешняя серьезность должна противоречить ситуации, в которую попадает герой, например: Он выглядел серьезно, как охранник, с которым решил пошутить Сталин.

Комический эффект можно также получить, если обыграть различные определения слова «серьезный»:  а) не легкомысленный; задумчивый, невеселый и б) сосредоточенный, озабоченный, проникнутый ответственностью. Под эту тему подходят большинство вариантов, которые Вам предложили, например: Он глядел серьезно (= сосредоточенно, озабоченно), как Петр первый на стрельцов.

Comment: У меня в тексте комический эффект достигается иным путем.

Comment: Мне интересно, какую художественную нагрузку в ОБЩЕМ ПЛАНЕ  может нести такое сравнение. Допустим, мы хотим передать содержание "он был очень серьезен". "Очень" - это не очень  выразительное слово, поэтому меняем его на сравнительный оборот. Но тогда этот оборот должен быть художественно выразительным, а как это сделать? Если мы говорим "голодный как волк", то такое сравнение понятно: волки всегда голодные. Но мы не можем сказать, что Петр Первый был всегда серьезным, значит, нужна ситуация, причем ярко эмоциональная, всеми понимаемая.

Comment: Мне кажется, что оборот с комическим, а не просто с  общеобразовательным содержанием, лучше справится с этой ролью.

Comment: Ну **Марк Из** как раз и предложил сравнения, отвечающие этим требованиям.

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно с таких ситуациях говорю (с оттенком иронии) - "С недетской серьезностью")))

Answer (score 0):

Как Воробьянинов в "Торг здесь неуместен!".